# How to modify zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs auto generated html?

Tags: php, yii

I need to modify Yii framework widget- zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs. 
By default it prints:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="/dr/dr/public_html/">Home</a> » <span>News</span></div>
```

But i need:

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="/dr/dr/public_html/">Home</a></li>
   <li>News</li>
</ul>
```

So how could i change it?

Comment: which version of yii are you using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. If you are using the latest version of [Yii (1.1.11)](http://www.yiiframework.com/news/55/yii-php-framework-1-1-11-is-released/), then you have a few *new* options in [CBreadcrumbs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBreadcrumbs), namely: `activeLinkTemplate` and `inactiveLinkTemplate` and using these (and also `tagName`) you can easily achieve your requirement.

   You just need to add values for these options, in the file where you are including the breadcrumb widget, by default, it's in a layout file : *protected/views/layouts/main.php* , like this:

   ```
   <?php if(isset($this->breadcrumbs)):?>
       <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
           'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,

           'tagName'=>'ul', // will change the container to ul
           'activeLinkTemplate'=>'<li><a href="{url}">{label}</a></li>', // will generate the clickable breadcrumb links 
           'inactiveLinkTemplate'=>'<li>{label}</li>', // will generate the current page url : <li>News</li>
           'homeLink'=>'<li><a href="'.Yii::app()->homeUrl.'">Home</a></li>' // will generate your homeurl item : <li><a href="/dr/dr/public_html/">Home</a></li>
       )); ?><!-- breadcrumbs -->
   <?php endif?>
   ```

   `'activeLinkTemplate'` generates links for active/clickable links, and `'inactiveLinkTemplate'` generates the current url which is not clickable and has no url.

   `{url}` and `{label}` are the *url* and *label* values provided by each view's breadcrumb object. eg:-

   ```
   // in some view.php file, you'll see this
   $this->breadcrumbs=array( // array is label=>url
       'Label1'=>array('route1'),
       'Label2'=>array('route2'),
       'Label3',
   );
   ```
2. If you are using versions before 1.1.11 then you'll have to `extend` the CBreadcrumbs class and modify the `run()` method to output breadcrumbs, enclosed in `<li>`. Once you see the existing `run()` method it'll become fairly clear to you how to do it.

**Edit:**

Missed out how to add the css class. You can do this by adding a class key-value in the htmlOptions array for this widget :

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
    'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,

    'tagName'=>'ul', // will change the container to ul
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'menu'),
    // ... rest of the code ...
 )); ?><!-- breadcrumbs -->
```

Comment: also added part to declare css class